# VideoPlayer height fit content / No black bars

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I wan't my VideoPlayer to have the height of the Video itself, so that there are no black bars. This way I can't set `height` to a constant value because on different devices with different width, the video has black bars. When I do this:

```
        <VideoPlayer #video
            src="https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
            autoplay="true"
            fill="false"
            muted="true">
        </VideoPlayer>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I know the video aspect ratio is 16/9.

I tried something like this: `[height]="video.clientWidth / (16/9)"` but it's not working.

What can i do?

Comment: I doubt we have any property named `clientWidth`, you might have you get the width and height of video source and calculate aspect ratio based on device width.

Comment: You mean based on the screen width? That seems like a poor way to me, is there really no way to get the width of an element?

Comment: Width of video? That's exactly what I meant. Check the `VideoSource` apis, you have option to get width and height of video, then definitely you might have to calculate the aspect ratio based on your screen size. Honestly I don't understand what seems poor here, this is just the case you would do for images too.